# For $x_0 \ge 1$, the sequence $(x_n)$ defined recursively by $x_{n+1} = (x_n +1/x_n)/2$ converges to $1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I'm doing *Problem II.3.4* in textbook **Analysis I** by Amann/Escher.

> [image]

After elementary transformations, the problem is equivalent to the below theorem:

> **Theorem:** For $x_0 \ge 1$, the sequence $(x_n)$ defined recursively by $x_{n+1} = (x_n +1/x_n)/2$ converges to $1$.

Could you please verify whether my attempt is fine or contains logical gaps/errors? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

---

**My attempt:**

First, we prove that this sequence is convergent. By AM-GM inequality, $x_{n+1} = (x_n +1/x_n)/2 \ge 1$ for all $n$, so the sequence is bounded from below. We have $x_{n+1} - x_n = (1-x_n^2)/(2x_n) \le 0$ and thus the sequence is decreasing. As such, $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =a \in \mathbb R^+$.

Next, we prove that $a=1$. We have

$$\begin{aligned}a &= \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n &&= \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n+1} \\ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n +1/x_n)/2 &&= \left ( \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n + \dfrac{1}{\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n} \right)/2 \\ &=(a+1/a)/2 \end{aligned}$$

This equation implies $a=1$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine. You  showed that the sequence is decreasing and  bounded below (thus convergent). You might elaborate that the equation $a = (a+1/a)/2$ has two solutions ($a= \pm 1$), but only $a=1$ can be the limit.

Alternatively observe that
$$
 0 \le x_{n+1} - 1 = \frac{(x_n-1)^2}{2x_n} \le \frac{(x_n-1)^2}{2}
$$
which also implies convergence $x_n \to 1$.

Comment: Your proof is much more elegant. Thank you so much ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint:

With $y = \frac{1}{2}( x + a/x)$ we have 
$$y \pm \sqrt{a} = \frac{(x\pm \sqrt{a})^2}{2 x}$$ so 
$$\frac{y-\sqrt{a}}{y+\sqrt{a}}= \left(\frac{x-\sqrt{a}}{x+\sqrt{a}}\right)^2$$

Now we are reduced to investigating the recurrence 
$$y_{n+1}= y_n^2$$